# Change Pivot's HeaderTemplate after initialization

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to change the HeaderTemplate of a Pivot when the PhoneApplicationPage Orientation changes to accomodate a different screen real-estate. The end-effect I'm trying to achieve is to shrink the Pivot Header FontSize in Landscape to make room for more vertical content.

The templates are declared in XAML as  Resources;

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="landscapePivotTitleTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="" Height="0"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="portraitPivotTitleTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="portraitPivotHeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="landscapePivotHeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I assign the DataTemplate from the Page's FrameworkElement.Resource ResourceDictionary in a handler for OrientationChanged;

```
void MainPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft || e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
    {
        pivot.HeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["landscapePivotHeaderTemplate"];
        pivot.TitleTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["landscapePivotTitleTemplate"];
    }
    else 
    {
        pivot.HeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["portraitPivotHeaderTemplate"];
        pivot.TitleTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["portraitPivotTitleTemplate"];
    }            
}
```

Using the above templates, the Title is correctly hidden by assigning to the TitleTemplate. However, it appears that it's only possible to set the Header template once - and subsequent assignments to the HeaderTemplate is only made effective by adding new PivotItem's.  Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I have just tried your code in a brand new pivot based solution and each time I change orientation the header is hidden/shown accordingly.

Comment: yes the header _title_ is, but the FontSize of the header for the pivot items are not changed - which is the problem

Comment: one workaround is to add and remove a blank pivotitem. It's just not very elegant..